# WinSCP Session.GetFiles error No such file or directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Using WinSCP with variables to automate downloading of specific file from remote root folder.  I have no problem connecting, but the code generates error 'No such file or directory' when attempting download.

Here's the code:

```
' Setup session variables, connect, and download file
Dim remotefile As String = "text.zip"
Dim localpath As String = "D:\Work\Returns\"

Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
With sessionOptions
   .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
   .HostName = myftpaddress
   .UserName = myftpuser
   .Password = myftppass
   .SshHostKeyFingerprint = SSH         
End With

Using session As New Session
  'go ahead & connect
  session.Open(sessionOptions)

  Dim transferOptions As New TransferOptions
  transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary
  Dim transferResult As TransferOperationResult
  'now get the file
  transferResult = session.GetFiles("/" & remotefile, localpath, False, transferOptions)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are trying to download does not exist.

You are most probably using a wrong path. Are you sure the account is chrooted? Isn't the path rather like `/user/home/text.zip`, rather than `/text.zip`?

Use WinSCP GUI to find the correct path to the file.

You can even have [WinSCP GUI generate the correct SFTP VB.NET download code for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

---

*If this does not help, we need to see your code session log file (set `Session.SessionLogPath`), as well as WinSCP GUI log file showing a download of the same file.*